# Stop/Delay cron on EC2 instance startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

We are running a set of cron jobs on an EC2 instance. We have two instance A and B in our deployment. Both A and B have Cron jobs that run on startup. We want to disable cron on B on startup until we stop server A and vis-versa when we start A.

Is it possible to automate this in any way? Can we use user-data to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to run your jobs only once, either on A or B, but not on both, correct?

You'll need some locking / semaphore mechanism, election of the "cron master", or something like that.

One way that I have done in the past is have *events* generated by **AWS CloudWatch Rule** every X-minutes, send those events to **SQS Queue** and all the servers in the cluster, i.e. A and B in your case, listen on the Queue and by the nature of the queue only one picks up the event and processes that.

So instead of having an internal cron job on each server and trying to synchronise them have a *cron job-like* service outside the servers and trigger the processing jobs through the SQS Queue. In simple cases like yours this should work very well.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I was just hoping for a way to just toggle the cron jobs. This seems a bit complicated.

Comment: @boygenius Sure, your other option is to build some complicated system to auto-toggle the cron jobs between the servers. Or do it manually. No, really, this SQS way is like 15 lines of Python code at most. :)

Comment: OKay. Will try it and let you know how it goes. Thanks!